# Flatpickr - min and max

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, flatpickr

I'm trying to understand the problem but can't see what I am missing.
I'm using Flatpickr and setting the minDate to the current day and the maxDate to 20 days after the current day.

```js
flatpickr("#datetimepicker", {
  enableTime: true,
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
  time_24hr: true,
  minDate: "today",
  maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(20) // 20 days from now
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<input type="datetime-local" id="datetimepicker" name="deadline" placeholder="Select date and time">
```

There aren't any errors in the browser Developer Tools' console.
I will appreciate any help!

Comment: You haven't defined any problem. On 27 May the earliest day selectable is 27 May and the last date is 16 June. Selected dates are shown as a timestamp in YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm format. Seems to me that's as expected.